# Stripe how to add payments method to popup form?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I have a button that pops up a window to pay with a card. But i need add more payments methods. Like that:
[image]

Can anyone know how to do this by modifying the code?

```html
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button active" data-key="pk_test_TzcRBxsPAsRFUBfvpkQr1Lgj" data-amount="999" data-name="Demo Site" data-description="Widget" data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png" data-locale="auto" data-notrack="">
</script>
<form action="your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_TzcRBxsPAsRFUBfvpkQr1Lgj"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="Example charge"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto">
  </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the payment methods via the dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payments/settings

Afterwards the new payment methods should automatically show up in Stripe Checkout.js.

Comment: If you're still having difficulties, you should try contacting Stripe support directly: https://support.stripe.com/contact?email=true